# iostream not found in Xcode

Tags: ios, zxing

I have problem including ZXing in my App. I get error: "iostream file not found".
I have done everything like in ZXing instruction but i can't get this working.
I'm including this in .mm file.
I use story boards this project is for iOS 6.0
This is error i get:

> In file included from
>   /Users/adam/Developer/project/project/SecondViewController.mm:11: In
>   file included from zxing/iphone/ZXingWidget/Classes/QRCodeReader.h:10:
>   In file included from
>   zxing/iphone/ZXingWidget/Classes/FormatReader.h:22:
>   zxing/cpp/core/src/zxing/common/Counted.h:23:10: fatal error:
>   'iostream' file not found

Any idea what can i do to get this working?

EDIT:

When i select Compile Source File As Objcetive-C++ project comiples without issues, BUT as i was told this is not god soultion beacuse this can make some problems later on with other parts of app.

Answer (score 14):

Just rename your implementation file with .mm extension instead of .m solve the issue.

Answer (score 9):

Project -> Build Settings -> Apple LLVM compiler 4.1-Language -> C++ Standard Library

Make sure to set that to "**libstdc++**"

Comment: I still get same error with yours solution, but look at my EDIT.

Comment: Try renaming your main.m to main.mm

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a new project, and choose "command line tool" as the template for your project. Choose C++. Paste your code into the new project (it should be a .cpp file). When you run the program, it should be able to include iostream without any problems.

Comment: It build successfully but there is always that nasty error dialog on the include line itself:(

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip: be sure the implement file extension is `.mm`

Answer (score -1):

placing `#import "QRCodeReader.h"` in the mm-file instead of it's header-file fixed the issue for me