# Very basic C++ issue (expected expression)?

Tags: c++

I have just started C++ and I'm not really sure what I am doing, but so far I have some "hello world" code from a tutorial.

```
   #include <iostream> 

//i only put this first line from users telling me to, it wasn't part of the original post. edited..


int main () {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler (Xcode for mac) says that there is an 'unexpected expression' right before the `cout` part of the code. I have no idea how to fix this problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you include iostream ?

Comment: Are you sure you compile in C++ not C mode?

Comment: did you #include <iostream> ?

Comment: Yes I put the #iostream but it said the file was not found

Comment: +1 For the way such a simple question was carefully proposed (right tags, decent code formatting, etc...)

Comment: #include <iostream> instead of #iostream

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to include the header that declares `cout`:

```
#include <iostream>
```

If you still encounter an error after fixing that, then it must be caused by something in `"ViewController.h"`.

**Update:** Also make sure the compiler recognises this as C++ by making sure the file extension is one of `.cc`, `.cxx` or `.cpp` (or `.mm` for Objective-C++.)

Comment: When I put this, the compiler gives me a bug?

Comment: @zingzing45 What does it say?

Comment: Should I take out the viewcontroller part?

Comment: @zingzing45: So what does the compiler say? Which line does it refer to? Is the problem in the code you've posted, or `"ViewController.h"`?

Comment: It only gives me an error on the iostream and it says the file is not found

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling C++ and not C?

Comment: @zingzing45: Then either your installation is faulty, or the compiler thinks you're compiling something other than C++. What file extension did you give the source file? It should be `.cc`, `.cpp` or `.cxx` to indicate C++.

Comment: The file extension is .m? I am using xcode.. so confusing

Comment: @zingzing45: `.m` is for Objective-C, not C++. Change it to one of `.cc`, `.cpp` or `.cxx`. (Or `.mm`, if you want to write Objective-C++.)

Comment: I think I managed to make it a .cpp file, thank you for that. However, now it tells me that there is a 'lexical or preprocessor issue'? The error is in the iostream line

Comment: @zingzing45: Are you still including `"ViewController.h"`? It sounds like that might be an Objective-C header. If you don't need it, get rid of it. If you do, and it is Objective-C, then you'll need to specify Objective-C++ (with a `.mm` extension). (If there's still a problem, then I'm afraid I'm out of ideas; I do very little MacOS programming).

Comment: I got rid of the viewcontroller part, and updated the original question with this info

Comment: @zingzing45: So what exactly does the error message say? There's usually something more specific than a category like "lexical or preprocessor issue".

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem. I made a completely new project ( I was using another project I made a month ago that apparently was C only or something) and when I opened it, it already had the hello world code I was trying to make. 
Anyways, thanks for your continued support, I don't think I would've made it out of this mess without you

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the earlier contributors, you will need to `#include <iostream>` which will provide the implementation for `std::cout`. For a simple hello world C++ program, you don't need `#include "ViewController.h"` (not sure what it is because it is not a standard include).

Why don't you remove the `#include "ViewController.h"` and then post the error that you are seeing? I'm sure folks here will be able to help you out.

Comment: Ok, I deleted the viewcontroller part

Comment: What's the error that you get? Please copy/paste the full error output by the compiler.

Comment: Code so far: #include <iostream>

int main () {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}

Error: ('iostream' file not found )on the first line

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with how XCode sets up its include paths.

Comment: Yeah, neither do I, which appears to be the main problem here. Fortunately, I managed to solve the problem by scrapping the project I was using and making a completely new one. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: `iostream` is C++ functionality. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with how XCode sets up its include paths or decides on the compilation (C, ObjectiveC, C++, ObjectiveC++).

This post might give you some ideas.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857805/iostream-not-found-in-xcode